# Site not displaying in mobile devices correctly

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport

this is my site. http://losroblesrestaurant.com.ar/index7b.php. When displayed on a phone the menu doesnt fit on the screen. I need it to be viewd at 347 px width. I have already tried with media queries and viewport but it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=700, user-scalable=no"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=80%, user-scalable=no"> and
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

none of wich make any difference at all

I am not allowed to post images, so please check this: http://losroblesrestaurant.com.ar/images/iphone-problem.jpg

The code for the phone has

```
body{min-width:347px;}
```

Comment: Show your code here and and your media queries, we shouldn't have to leave stackoverflow to see your problem, at least provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Hum... what's the problem exactly ? Can you share some code that we can fix ?

Comment: Ok, sorry, this is my first question here. I need a 347 px width (not 572 px as saaid before) to fit in the screen, without horizontal scrollbar. For widths < 777 px, my media query is body{min-width:347px;}. This gets a horizontal scroll bar when diplayed at less than this width. I tried setting the vewport to device-width, to 80% percentage, and to 700 px, but it still shows the same way. My upper menu is in a fixed position, so i want the site to be displayed in the screen with a minumin of 347px with no horizontal scroll. I hope this clears the issue

Comment: Edit your question and post the relevant code, not just partial lines. It's better to put slightly more than needed than only small bits when requested. Sometimes one need the all picture to be able to find the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You set a fixed min-width on .inner.  You need to remove it.

You also have a width of 990px on .inner-blanco.  Change it to 100%.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work, it shows the same thing

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the wrong element names.  I edited it to reflect the correct names.

Comment: I overwrote this in telefono.css for minwidth:700px, but still doesnt work.

Comment: You need to remove min width completely. If you set it to 700px it's going to be 700px not 347px. If you want further help and still do not understand please post some updated code